# When I generate the build of my react app with vite js and launch it, it gives a not found when reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I need the support of the wise

I have a React app that I develop with the support of Vite, in this project I use react-router-dom to manage route protection but I have a problem, when I generate the build and launch it, for example, with vscode live server or with IIS access normal to the app, but when reloading it is as if it lost connection and in the terminal it gives me a not found error, I add the complete error:

`Cannot GET /cau/auth/login`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Do you know what could cause this problem? I will thank you very much.

I was expecting my build to pick up but it fails to reload.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.